# Is it bad practice to configure a single php file for the default location in your server block?

Tags: php, nginx

First off I am new to nginx, and I have tried searching for an answer to this.  Haven't had any luck. I am interested to know if this is seen as bad practice.

My goal is that pretty much all process routing is handled by PHP. Images and static files can be served directly. As I understand the following config will mean all requests will attempt to process the file, if it doesn't exist - it will push the request to *index.php*.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Is there anything inherently bad about what I am suggesting?

Images and static files can still be reached directly from their URL - everything else needs to run via the PHP script. As it checks user authentication and access controls.

Comment: This looks alright to me :)

Comment: After searching some more, I came across the 'front controller pattern' note on http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls - basically said that this is fine. Thanks for the tick @Jack.

Answer (score 1):

See: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls under the header **Front Controller Pattern based packages**

There is a whole section talking about how this is fairly standard, and the config in the question is good to go.